# Telegram software errors are popping up, what did I do wrong?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am making a software for telegram, which will send a certain number of messages in the form of stickers through the telegram chat database, after the end of the cycle wait 24 hours and repeat the cycle. but the code itself does not work for some reason.

Here is the code itself:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import time
import datetime

API_ID = 'api_id'
API_HASH = 'api_hash'

messages_sent = 0

def main():
    global messages_sent

    chat_usernames = ['@forexjobinkiev', '@spb_work_choogl', '@temshchik_chat', '@work_online_today', '@freelancerchat1', '@chat_sportbetwiner', '@SravkiS', '@dropshiping_tovarka_ua', '@Kiev_Work_Job682', '@robota_com5']

    with TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
        while True:
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

            if current_time.hour == 0 and current_time.minute == 0:
                messages_sent = 0

            if messages_sent < 35:
                for chat_username in chat_usernames:
                    chat_entity = client.get_entity(chat_username)
                    for sticker_id in ['CAACAgEAAxkBAAK2RmTUSWd8kMnKSh4vNz_YpKaRGL2tAAIuAwAC4WihRo38v4W03s7TMAQ', 'CAACAgEAAxkBAAK2SGTUSYInvjbUPyaP3mpG22JsVhjiAAIYBAACwHKgRlJDWLOjrJKVMAQ']:
                        client.send_sticker(chat_entity, sticker=sticker_id)
                        messages_sent += 1
                        if messages_sent >= 35:
                            break
                        time.sleep(20)

            next_day = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            time_to_wait = datetime.datetime.combine(next_day.date(), datetime.time.min) - datetime.datetime.now()
            time.sleep(time_to_wait.total_seconds())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Mistakes that pop up:

```
Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead :15
PEP 8: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1 :10
PEP 8: E501 line too long (220 > 120 characters) :13
PEP 8: E501 line too long (189 > 120 characters) :25
PEP 8: E305 expected 2 blank lines after class or function definition, found 1 :36
```

Maybe I don't have all the libraries, I'm still a beginner, help me please

I've tried a lot of things, still no luck(

Comment: It's nice to catch PEP8 exceptions, but you'll want to focus only on the first one as a 'mistake'. The rest will depend on your own or your team's preferred style.